# read expressions at the command line

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a calculator which is able to read expression like (5+12*5)^2; it is not a polish calculator.

For the moment I'm focusing on how to read the numbers and store them inside a linked list. The program should read a line compute the result and wait for the next input (like commands are take in a shell).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX 100

struct n{
    double value;
    char op;
    struct n *next;
};

void print_list(struct n *head);
void add_item(struct n **ptr, double *data);
void free_all(struct n *head);
void f(double x);

int main()
{
    struct n *head = NULL;

    char *buf = malloc(MAX * sizeof (*buf));
    int n;
    double num;

    for(;;) {

        if(fgets(buf, MAX, stdin) == NULL)
            return 0;

        while (*buf != '\n') {

            if (isdigit(*buf)) {
                sscanf(buf, "%lf%n", &num, &n);
                add_item(&head, &num);
                buf += n;
            }

            if (!isdigit(*buf)){
                buf++;
            }

            print_list(head);   
        }
       free(head);
    }



    return 0;
}

void print_list(struct n *head) {

    if (head != NULL) {
        f(head->value);
        print_list(head->next);
    }
}

void add_item(struct n **ptr, double *data)
{
        struct n *item = malloc(sizeof *item);

        item->value = *data;
        item->next = *ptr;
        item->op = '*';
        *ptr = item;
}

void free_all(struct n *head)
{
    struct n *tmp;

    while (head != NULL)
    {
       tmp = head;
       head = head->next;
       free(tmp);
    }
}

void f(double x)
{
    double i, r = modf(x, &i);

    if(fabs(r)<.00001)
        printf("%.f ",i);

    else printf("%f ",x);
}
```

I'm using fgets and I'm able to read the input but the program gets into an infinite loop. I'm not sure what's the best function to read data for this purpose.

Comment: `if(fgets(buf, MAX, stdin) == EOF)` <<-- fgets() never returns EOF.

Comment: Maybe you could change the condition to `if(fgets(buf, MAX, stdin) == NULL)`

Comment: “how to read the numbers and store them inside a linked list” — why? This isn’t a particularly useful representation for an expression parser.

Comment: the question is about reading data, for the moment I'm not focusing on parsing I could have used also an array.

Comment: On your 'while' loop, add a condition for the string terminator: `while (*buf && *buf != '\n') {`

Comment: Please find out where the compiler warnings go to and act upon them!

Comment: Also: by incrementing buf, you loose grip on the pointer returned by malloc(). So you can never reuse or free it. Use a separate pointer (or an index) to walk the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake

```
if (isdigit(*buf)) {
    sscanf(buf, "%lf%n", &num, &n);
    add_item(&head, &num);
    buf += n; // Here we are incrementing buf
}

if (!isdigit(*buf)){ // So here we are looking at index buf+n
    buf++;
}
```

What you need to do here is a couple of `if else`. But another thing here is that it is pretty redundant to first check if it is a digit, and then check if it's not. Rewrite to this:

```
if (isdigit(*buf)) {
    sscanf(buf, "%lf%n", &num, &n);
    add_item(&head, &num);
    buf += n;
} else {
    buf++;
}
```

But, as have already been mentioned in comments, a linked list is not a very good strategy when constructing a parser. You should use a tree instead. You should also read about grammars to define the syntax. Read about grammars here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar